# Corona - works on simulator but not on real Android device (system.pathForFile)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have this simple line of code that works perfectly on the simulator but gets a `nil` on a actual android device:

```
local path = system.pathForFile( nil, system.ResourceDirectory)


print('path', path)

path = path .. "/assets/audios"
```

on the android device I get
Runtime Error  .......attempt to concatenate local 'path' (a nil value)

I read the the android docs and it says you don't need permission to read the internal storage.

What's causing this error?
How to solve it?

Do I need to add any special permissions to use `pathForFile` in android?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..found something that works not the android device.
It is bit of a cheat/workaround...but as long as it works....

so this does not work on the device but works on the simulator:

```
local path = system.pathForFile( nil, system.ResourceDirectory)


print('path', path)

path = path .. "/assets/audios"
```

This however works which will get you the same result just through different steps:

```
local path = system.pathForFile('assets/audios/x.wav', system.ResourceDirectory)

    -- path = path .. "/assets/audios"
    path = string.gsub( path, 'x.wav', '' )
```